# Pass null value to stored procedure in Mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sqlyog

I am creating a stored procedure in Mysql. How can I pass value that will accept null?

I know that in SQL Server 2008 R2, I do like this

```
@name varchar(10) = null
```

but how can I do this in Mysql?

```
    DELIMITER $$
         CREATE PROCEDURE `ipm_website`.`uspInsertFuelBuyDetails`( promotion_code VARCHAR(45)=NULL,eventid INT,Erid INT, first_name VARCHAR(255)=NULL,last_Name)
     BEGIN
       INSERT INTO ipm_fuel.TBL_EVENT_PAYMENTS 
      (promotion_code, EVENT_ID, EVENT_RATE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, PHONE_NUMBER, EMAIL, ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2,
       CITY, STATE, ZIPCODE, card_type, card_number, exmonth, exyear, total_amount,
        admin_fee, license_plate, guid, date_added) 
VALUES (promotion_code, eventid, Erid ,first_name ,last_Name ,phoneNo , email, address1, address2, city , state, ZIPCODE, card_type, card_no, exmonth, exyear, total_amount, admin_fee, licanse_plate,
         guid, date_added);
       END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

How can I do that, and how to allow null value in parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your query there's no need to pass the *NULL*, you can simply skip the column where you want to put *NULL* in the insert clause.